# Whats the real benefits of using the TFS Build 2013?

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/whats-new-in-tfs-2013-build/

I've only recently learned of the new TFS Build 2013 workflow. XAML and PowerShell, neither of which I want to use.

We have a couple of thousand lines of msbuild script which does everything imaginable from change the version number to create help files.
I've struggled for the past 2 weeks to make them work on TFS Build 2013 and VSO but I do think I can make it work. But its time to face the reality, it's a hack (We do not have a build team).

I think we should bite the bullet and move to the new process.
I have some worries however:

- Is the new process a bigger burden to maintain?
- Will this process       change again in the new couple of years?
- What's peoples experiences with conversion from the old msbuild
  scripts and the maintenance of      the new XAML and Powershell?
- Is there any benefit to the XAML and       Powershell approach vs
  msbuild?

Comment: If you're worried about new processes you should take a look at what the future is preparing (build vNext): 
- cross-platform builds
- no need to learn new language
- no need for Visual Studio
- XAML builds will not receive new functionalities

Comment: great http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2015/01/15/tfs-build-vnext-ndash-a-preview.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your concerns...

> Is the new process a bigger burden to maintain?

If you don't change the default workflows it's fine. As soon as you go editing the workflows you'll wished you spent the time fixing your MSBuild script. It gets ugly fast in there.

> Will this process change again in the new couple of years?

As others have said, the XAML based builds are 'done'. You'll want to invest time looking at the new build system for the future. For now, I'd stick with MSBuild and take the time to get it working.

> What's peoples experiences with conversion from the old msbuild scripts and the maintenance of the new XAML and Powershell?

Havig done both, I much prefer using MSBuild. I use the upgrade template as a way of running my msbuild script.

> Is there any benefit to the XAML and Powershell approach vs msbuild?

Yes. You get a lot more power and control of the build and the way the build works allows you to scale things in interesting ways. On the flip side, with great power comes great complexity and the XAML approach quickly gets overwhelming.

--

My suggestion for you would be to take the time to get the MSBuild scripts working again, and then start preparing yourself for the new build system when it becomes available.

Comment: This suits me. In the interim I'm going to simplify my msbuild scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You should look to use the new Build vNext coming in TFS 2015 and VSO.

http://nakedalm.com/create-a-build-vnext-build-definition-on-vso/

The new build system does not use XAML and supports many 'make' systems including MSBuild. The best investment of your time, if you are building on windows, would be PowerShell.

Comment: great article. So TFS build 2015 is not ready yet! looks good though, I'll wait for the full release.